# Взять определенный отрезок цифр из числа C#

Tags: c#

Например есть число в формате string: 100466
На python-е это выглядит так: 100466[0:2] -> берется число 10
Как такое же реализовать в C#?

Comment: `100466.ToString()[..2]`, если надо именно число, то можно еще в `int.Parse()` это все завернуть.

Comment: @aepot - Вы не только дьявольски умны, но и дьявольски быстры :-)

Comment: Если число уже `string`, то `"100466"[..2]` получится.